# Get data array with looping for

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to display data with looping for in javascript, My data from firebase and I use codeigniter 4 framewok, so I code like this

```
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDF7wuv3zF8yQmyoLz271z9ZY4U2_DaSII",
    authDomain: "tescrud-7a01e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://tescrud-7a01e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "tescrud-7a01e",
    storageBucket: "tescrud-7a01e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "522079588783",
    appId: "1:522079588783:web:d2aed3d4c107ad4dc31f5a",
    measurementId: "G-0EYRKM693R"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 
    var database = firebase.database();
 
    var lastIndex = 0;
 
    // Get Data
    firebase.database().ref('Monitor/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var value = snapshot.val();
        var htmls = [];

        $.each(value, function (index, value) {
            if (value) {
                var d = new Date(value.timestamp);
                var timeStampCon = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
                var x;
                htmls.push('<tr>\
                <td>' + value.noWO + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.namaMitra + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.alamat + '</td>\
                <td>' + timeStampCon + '</td>\
                <td>' + {for(x = 0; x <= value.imageList.length; x++){
                    '<img src="' + value.imageList[x].imageUrl + '" style="margin-right: 5px;" width="50px" height="50px">
                }}
                + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.imageList[0].imageTitle + '</td>\
                <td align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> </td>\
            </tr>');
            }
            lastIndex = index;
        });
        $('#tbody').html(htmls);
        $("#submitStudent").removeClass('disabled');
    });

</script>
```

but, I found error in console when run application like this, can anyone help me what's wrong I do

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an apostrophe missing after line 37 which is causing the syntax error but it doesn't look like your code would work even without the syntax error. Here's an approach with ES6 to accomplish what you're trying to do.

`value.imageList.map(el => '<img src="' + el.imageUrl + '" style="margin-right: 5px;" width="50px" height="50px">').join("")` This goes through all the imageList elements, mapping them into the `<img>` tags and then `.join`ing them together.

Here's your entire code with my change in it.

```
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDF7wuv3zF8yQmyoLz271z9ZY4U2_DaSII",
    authDomain: "tescrud-7a01e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://tescrud-7a01e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "tescrud-7a01e",
    storageBucket: "tescrud-7a01e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "522079588783",
    appId: "1:522079588783:web:d2aed3d4c107ad4dc31f5a",
    measurementId: "G-0EYRKM693R"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 
    var database = firebase.database();
 
    var lastIndex = 0;
 
    // Get Data
    firebase.database().ref('Monitor/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var value = snapshot.val();
        var htmls = [];

        $.each(value, function (index, value) {
            if (value) {
                var d = new Date(value.timestamp);
                var timeStampCon = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
                var x;
                htmls.push('<tr>\
                <td>' + value.noWO + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.namaMitra + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.alamat + '</td>\
                <td>' + timeStampCon + '</td>\
                <td>' +
                // Maps each element in the 'imageList' array into the img elements and then uses the .join method to combine them
                value.imageList.map(el => `<img src="${el.imageUrl}" style="margin-right: 5px;" width="50px" height="50px">`).join("")
                + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.imageList[0].imageTitle + '</td>\
                <td align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> </td>\
            </tr>');
            }
            lastIndex = index;
        });
        $('#tbody').html(htmls);
        $("#submitStudent").removeClass('disabled');
    });

</script>
```

Note: I did not analyze all your code, there may still be syntax or logical errors in it.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried and succeeded @Joshua

Answer (score 0):

well I just  came  back here  to that joshua had  already solved your  problem but  the  error  you were  getting  was  because for loop didn't  returned  a  string(hence the  expected  token error, instead  of string  it got nothing  to add e.g x= "" + no string here +""). It iterated  over the  elements  in array and  didn't  return anything. you could  make  a  function to return the  string(exactly what joshua has  done ). after you do return a  string to it, you'll see that the  error changes to a  missing  ' in your  code.  Here is  a  simple  solution to your  issue:

```
    <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDF7wuv3zF8yQmyoLz271z9ZY4U2_DaSII",
    authDomain: "tescrud-7a01e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://tescrud-7a01e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "tescrud-7a01e",
    storageBucket: "tescrud-7a01e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "522079588783",
    appId: "1:522079588783:web:d2aed3d4c107ad4dc31f5a",
    measurementId: "G-0EYRKM693R"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 
    var database = firebase.database();
 
    var lastIndex = 0;
 
    // Get Data
    firebase.database().ref('Monitor/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var value = snapshot.val();
        var htmls = [];

        $.each(value, function (index, value) {
            if (value) {
                var d = new Date(value.timestamp);
                var timeStampCon = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
                var x;
                htmls.push('<tr>\
                <td>' + value.noWO + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.namaMitra + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.alamat + '</td>\
                <td>' + timeStampCon + '</td>\
                <td>' +  getResultString(value)
                + '</td>\
                <td>' + value.imageList[0].imageTitle + '</td>\
                <td align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> </td>\
            </tr>');
            }
            lastIndex = index;
        });
        $('#tbody').html(htmls);
        $("#submitStudent").removeClass('disabled');
    });

    function getResultString(parameter){
      var res = ''; 
      for(x = 0 ; x <= parameter.imageList.length ; x++){
                    res += '<img src="' + parameter.imageList[x].imageUrl + '" style="margin-right: 5px;" width="50px" height="50px">'
                }
                return res;
    }

</script>
```